# Certain fonts not working for UIButton in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, xcode6

When visually editing my app using the Storyboard in XCode 6 (also available in XCode 5) I can change the font of `UIButton`s using the Attributes Inspector. I can change from "System - System" to "Custom" which allows me to change the Family. However, it appears only some families work, as when I try to select others such as "Iowan Old Style" the selection doesn't stick and it shows the previous font. Is this a bug or are fonts restricted in some way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Beta 5. I've experienced the same issues and verified that they programmatically work just setting them via `UIFont`. This is also a regression since this was working in Beta 4.

Unfortunately, it looks like we're gonna just have to wait until the next beta release (beta 6) for a fix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. Maybe I can get away with editing the storyboard plist manually, or did all your previously selected fonts stop working completely with Beta 5?

Comment: @bloudermilk I'm pretty sure editing the plist will work well. The only thing that's really broken is the selection. Not the functionality.